# You must provide a value expression following the '-' operator error when using product code for MsiZap

Tags: powershell

This Powershell script calls MsiZap on a remote server to delete a software based on it's product code if it exists.

I'm getting a parsing error saying the following:

```
At C:\Scripts\Remove Tools\Remove-Tools.ps1:41 char:83
+ ... {57753043-0E65-4B13-9AF0-AC09CFC29C03} }
+                    ~
You must provide a value expression following the '-' operator.
At C:\Scripts\Remove Tools\Remove-Tools.ps1:41 char:83
+ ... {57753043-0E65-4B13-9AF0-AC09CFC29C03} }
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token '4B13-9AF0-AC09CFC29C03' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedValueExpression
```

Here's all of the switching code:

```
foreach ($product in $products){
Switch -wildcard($product.IdentifyingNumber){

    "*C18D2775-33F4-4CE9-B071-4ECC78DA5E31*" {  "Removing Software" >> "$spath\log.log"
                                                ./psexec \\$computer -s -w c:\ cmd /c msizap.exe TW {C18D2775-33F4-4CE9-B071-4ECC78DA5E31} }

    "*59AB19CE-2706-4F7B-B567-403BB584D92E*" {  "Removing Software" >> "$spath\log.log"
                                                ./psexec \\$computer -s -w c:\ cmd /c msizap.exe TW {59AB19CE-2706-4F7B-B567-403BB584D92E} }

    "*57753043-0E65-4B13-9AF0-AC09CFC29C03*" {  "Removing Software" >> "$spath\log.log"
                                                ./psexec \\$computer -s -w c:\ cmd /c msizap.exe TW {57753043-0E65-4B13-9AF0-AC09CFC29C03} }                                            

    "*4B932CA6-727B-4948-91E3-FFCF75CE3478*" {  "Removing Software" >> "$spath\log.log"
                                                ./psexec \\$computer -s -w c:\ cmd /c msizap.exe TW {4B932CA6-727B-4948-91E3-FFCF75CE3478} }

    }
```

}

The following line is the one causing the error:

```
"*57753043-0E65-4B13-9AF0-AC09CFC29C03*" {  "Removing Software" >> "$spath\log.log"
                                                ./psexec \\$computer -s -w c:\ cmd /c msizap.exe TW {57753043-0E65-4B13-9AF0-AC09CFC29C03} }
```

The other lines, which are identical (besides the change in product code) do not get this error.

Comment: It is a coincidence that some work, they are all broken. `{}` is a PowerShell scriptblock - see how you use it around the switch statement code blocks. If you need it to be a GUID string to pass as a parameter to msizap, you need to quote it `"{C18...-...-}"`. The reason this third one fails particularly is because 57753043 looks like a number, which triggers arithmetic evaluation, 0e65 looks like a number in scientific notation, then 4b13 isn't a number so it breaks. All the others have text in the first block so they all look like strings and don't trigger arithmetic evaluation.